# Rails routing: organizing routes under a namespace having its own route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

The general goal is to organize some routes under a `/configuration/*` path mapped to a `Configurations::` controller's namespace. For example, `/configuration/teams` mapped to `Configurations::TeamsController#index`, offering users the ability to configure the teams they belong to.

In addition, I'd like a single route (for example `/configuration` mapped to `ConfigurationsController#show`) as an access to other resource specific routes. In this page, users would retrieve a list of resource they can configure.

**What would be the most conventionnal way to proceed ?** Considering I'm not attached to these specific paths, feel free to suggest other approaches.

**Does having a separate controller for configuration make sense to you?** Maybe using `edit` actions would be more consistent. In the case of teams, for example, it'll allow users to edit fields on the `teams` table, but also to create/revoke JWTs stored on a separate table, as well as other associations. I were thinking of a `Configurations::TeamsController` as a way to aggregate the different models (teams, JWT, ...)

---

PS: question has been largely edited since @anpeterka's answer and @Mike Szyndel's comment.

Comment: For the sake of whoever has to work on this after you: please don't. Just call it ConfigurationController, Rails guides has a section on singular controllers

Comment: What do you mean ? Having the root route being: `get '/configuration', to: 'configuration#show', as: :configuration` ? Both singular and plural forms make sense to me, as singular could refer to the configuration's homepage, and plural could refer to the page to access configurations subsections. There's more than "team" that will be nested under /configuratoin

Comment: teams should be it's own controller. configuration should be a singular controller. simple as that

Comment: i'm not sure to understand, guides are using plural controller for singular resource: `get 'profile', to: 'users#show'`

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong!

Comment: @MikeSzyndel having plural names for the controllers for singular resources can seem somewhat confusing but the rationale is that it greatly simplefies the code for deriving controller names from model names and routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clean resource oriented way to do this in Rails would be:

```
resource :configuration, only: :show do
  resources :teams, only: :show, module: :configurations
end
```

Since `configuration` is a singlular resource the `GET /configurations` should route to the show action and not `index`. After all there is only ever one resource to show.

If you want to add the same options to a group of resources and not repeat yourself use `scope`:

```
resource :configuration, only: :show do
  scope module: :configurations do
    resources :teams, only: :show
    resources :foos
    resources :bars
  end
end
```

What the namespace macro actually does is just `scope 'foo', module: :foo`.  It's not some magic concept.

> I were thinking of a Configurations::TeamsController as a way to aggregate the different models (teams, JWT, ...)

That doesn't sound like a very good idea as you're intentionally creating a junk drawer / god class.

Think in terms of resources and follow the Single Responsibity Principle. A controller should only be responsible for CRUD'ing a single resource. Even that sometimes stretches the idea that a class should have one job.

Authorizations in the form of JWT's should absolutely have their own controller(s).

Grouping related classes together in a module though does make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems really clean to me and perfectly fits my needs. Would it be a bad idea for you if the "god class" (aka `ConfigurationController#show`)  simply lists the configurable resources ? I'd express its responsability as "providing an interface listing the resources that can be configured" (the configuration as such taking place in the appropriate `Configurations::FoosController`). And yes, JWT authorization is taking place in other controllers, here I just want to provide a way to create/revoke tokens

Comment: Great answer, I'm just personally not so fond of the ` module: :configurations` as it repeats `configuration` from line before. For that I'd prefer to have separate namespace

Answer (score 2):

> Update: Both answer and question were edited multiple times. Current answer is more of an overview than answer to currently asked question.

Aware that I'm not providing what you asked (but hopefully understanding what you are trying to achieve), I'll lay down multiple approaches I can think of.

Keep in mind I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails.

### resources

Rails is pretty resourceful, and rewards those who are `REST`ed.
Ok, seriously, what I'm talking about?
Seeing everything in your app as a resource can help in structuring your app (controllers and routes in this case) in the most simple, elegant way.
What resources do we have here?

It seems like there is `Configuration` (probably as in `CurrentUserConfiguration` or something), and `TeamConfiguration`.
These will *probably* have separate controllers - `ConfigurationsController` and `TeamConfigurationsController` (mind that controllers are always plural, even when it seems like it should be singular).
`ConfigurationController` doesn't need any additional params, `TeamConfigurationController` does (probably as `team_id`).

Ok, now we do want some endpoint for these resources.
We want simple enpoint for [singular resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) configuration:

```
configuration_path  GET /configuration(.:format)  configurations#show
```

```rb
# routes.rb

resource :configuration, only: :show
```

How about the team configuration? Well, we have multiple options.

Either we just take these as two different resources, and then it's simple:

```rb
# routes.rb

resources :team_configuration, only: :show
# this produces team_configuration_path GET /team_configuration/:id(.:format)   team_configuration#show
```

Let's say now that we just want to conceptually keep all `configurations` (as we will add some other) together. What are our options?

#### nested resources

[Nesting resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) can be pretty powerful way of keeping things together. How might it look in our case?

**team has configuration**

If you look at it from the point that resource `Team` has its resource `Configuration`, it might make sense to nest them:

```rb
# routes.rb

resources :teams do
  resource :configuration, only: :show
end
# this produces
# team_configuration_path   GET /teams/:team_id/configuration(.:format) configurations#show
```

Mind that this way, `ConfigurationsController` is expecting, so we must specify our controller:

`resource :configuration, only: :show, controller: "team_configuration"`.

Ok, this seems bit complicated and nonelegant. Maybe other way around:

**configuration has team (configuration)**

How about this:

```rb
# routes.rb

resource :configuration, only: :show do
  resources :team, only: :show
end
# this produces
#configuration_team_path    GET /configuration/team/:id(.:format)   team#show
```

Nice, but we have similar problem - now `TeamController` is expected. We can do the same - specifying controller, but it's still not very clean.
Let's forget resources and look into

### namespace

Maybe our case of keeping things together is not about resource and their relationship, but just about making arbitrary bundle `configuration` where we shove all our related things:

```rb
# routes.rb

resource :configuration, only: :show

namespace :configuration do
  resources :teams, only: :show
end
```

This produces

```
configuration_path      GET /configuration(.:format)              configurations#show
configuration_team_path GET /configuration/teams/:id(.:format)  configuration/teams#show
```

Pretty nice, right? Although there's `Configuration::TeamsController` expected - but that might be a good thing! If we are really serious about having namespace/"module" `configuration`, we might as well reflect that in our controller!

## Closing thoughts

Wheh, what a journey. I learned quite a bit, trying all the different approaches. I was convinced on the beginning that nested routing is "the right way", but now it seems that it really isn't and I just wanted to use one way I learned a lot about.

Approaching this problem, I try to find "what's the most Rails way to do this?". Luckily, Rails is very helpful in this - everytime you stray from it, you have to write additional code. Less code means closer to defaults. That's strength of [**convention over configuration**](https://rubyonrails.org/doctrine#convention-over-configuration).
Yes, I can change `:team_id` to `:id` or other way around, I can specify different controller, I can use namespacing, nesting, mix resources with explicit `get`s. But it smells. And every change costs something - readability, cohesion.

Again - I don't have that much experience with Rails. There might be better ways. I'm just summing how I can think about this sort of topic, in a hope it might be helpful for other people too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your example are close to what I want, but is it possible to have `resources :configurations, only: :show do { resources :team, only: :show }`, and just ignore configuration's ID ? Indeed I want a singular resource (`/configuration` to `configurations#show`), and a namespace having the same structure (`/configuration/something`, to `configurations/something#action`)

Comment: It's probably possible, but why is it so important for you that the path looks this way?

I just edited my answer, providing another view - still not doing your path, but for reason stated, I'd recommend it!

If you really really want your format path, using nested resource you can achieve it this way:

```
resource :configuration, only: :show do
    resources :teams, only: :show, controller: "team_configuration"
end
```

And using namespace:

```
resource :configuration, only: :show

  namespace :configuration do
    resources :teams, only: :show
  end
```

Comment: It's not important at all, I thought it'd be a nice way to organize URIs and controllers into a dedicated namespace, and having only `edit` and `update` action in each controller. Thanks for sharing other approach, I'll re-read guides and try to pick the most conventionnal way to proceed

Comment: Ok, I rewrote my answer completely again. Using namespace seems sensible to me now from our discussion. I found it really useful to experiment, try multiple ways and see what "clicks".

Comment: You don't need namespace. While it works it's messy. Just use the `module` option (`resources :teams, only: :show, module: :configurations`).

Comment: Re-reading your answer is a great reminder of different approaches. Even if I've tried most of them, it's always good to have in synthesis (specially because I tend to forget RoR router's DSL). Thanks again for your time and the things I've learned through your answer ! @max shows us the way (again)

Answer (score 1):

It might help to mention Mastodon's approach:

by clicking the "Preference" button, users are redirected to a default configuration page as so:

```rb
namespace :settings do
  get :preferences, to: redirect('/settings/preferences/appearance')

  namespace :preferences do
    resource :appearance, only: [:show, :update], controller: :appearance
    resource :notifications, only: [:show, :update]
    resource :other, only: [:show, :update], controller: :other
  end
end
```

No super-controller and both `/settings` and `/settings/preferences` leads to a redirection. Each entry in the side menu is associated with a small controller which inherits from `Settings::BaseController` (which defines common behiavour such as `layout`, access control, cache, ...)